# Drag and drop on Physice Body in libgdx

Tags: drag-and-drop, box2d, libgdx

I am using libgdx for rendering and Box2D for physics.what is the way to do drag and drop on physics body in libgdx.(touch and drag drop)

Comment: use this link https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/box2d/Box2DTest.java.

Comment: It is fine but i do not need any gravity.If there is no gravity in the above example then when i drop the body at some point, it is continuously moving

Comment: so what you can do is just play with gravity scale of the body. Add gravity your world. and then the bodies for which you don't need gravity make the gravity scale to be zero. when you touch the object and create a mouse joint make the gravity scale to be 1 and when you destroy the mouse joint change the scale to zero again.

Comment: i did it .... but still it is not working.When i drop the body it is moving and rotating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mouse joint to the body which you want to drag and drop. Using mouse joint you can pick up body and drop it where you want.